What does Soft Delete mean in Google Cloud Storage?
Today I received an email that I will be charged from June 1st for using Soft Delete feature. I couldn't understand what it is exactly!
I never heard about this feature and I never activated it.

It's relatively easy: Cloud Storage do not delete immediately the object. It keep it in "logical delete state" also named "soft delete" (it marks it as deleted), and then, after X days (7 by default), the objects are definitively deleted.
Like a "trash" folder in Windows or other system: the files are truly deleted only when you empty the trash.
Therefore, if you have a lot of file deletion (or move, or rewrite), it will cost you 7 days more in storage.
Note: the feature has been activated by default on all the existing buckets, with a default value of 7 days
